# SizeChanged not firing for elements on Canvas

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a simple UWP app defined as follows:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace SizeChangedBug
{
  public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
  {
    public MainPage() {
      this.InitializeComponent();
      this.Rectangle.SizeChanged += Rectangle_SizeChanged;
    }

    private void Rectangle_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
      Debug.WriteLine("Rectangle_SizeChanged");
    }
  }
}
```

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="SizeChangedBug.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SizeChangedBug"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

  <Canvas>
    <Slider x:Name="Slider" Orientation="Vertical" Width="80" Height="300" Value="400" Minimum="0" Maximum="600" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle" Margin="200,200" Width="{Binding Value, ElementName=Slider}" Height="{Binding Value, ElementName=Slider}" Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
  </Canvas>
</Page>
```

The problem is that SizeChanged never fires and Rectangle_SizeChanged never gets called when the size of Rectangle changes. Am i missing something or it's a bug in UWP? The below XAML with Canvas replaced with Grid works.

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="SizeChangedBug.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SizeChangedBug"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

  <Grid>
    <Slider x:Name="Slider" Orientation="Vertical" Width="80" Height="300" Value="400" Minimum="0" Maximum="600" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle" Margin="200,200" Width="{Binding Value, ElementName=Slider}" Height="{Binding Value, ElementName=Slider}" Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, we are still researching your question. But maybe you can tell us why you are using the `SizeChanged` event here? Knowing this helps us provide a better solution. We recommend that you use [Transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/transforms), which will be smoother than using `Transform` instead of modifying `Width` / `Height`.

Comment: Hi @RichardZhang-MSFT, will Transform trigger SizeChanged? The solution is pretty complicated to be posted here, so i distilled it into a simple example that should be easy to comprehend/debug.

Answer (score -1):

Canvas uses absolute positioning as its layout technique for its contained child elements. So SizeChanged event of the child will not trigger. It doesn't consider sizing or scaling. it depends on x,y coordinates. I am quoting exact lines from Microsoft document.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas#remarks

> Because absolute positioning does not take into account the size of
>   the app window, scaling, or other user-selected sizing, using a
>   container element that adapts to different orientations and screen
>   settings, such as Grid or StackPanel, is often a better choice than
>   using Canvas.

You can read more about it in [Layout Panels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/layouts-with-xaml#layout-panels)

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question is why element's SizeChanged doesn't fire when it's placed inside Canvas.

Comment: Element which is placed inside canvas will not get affected by any sizing factor. Canvas holds something like drawing paper. What places in them is just placed like in x,y co ordinates. Will not affect size changed

Comment: The size of the the element is not changed by Canvas, it's changed by Slider value. Check the xaml code.

Comment: Yeah I saw that anything that contained within canvas will not  trigger size changed. That’s simple and that’s the answer as it uses absolute positioning

Comment: What does it have to do with absolute positioning? The size of rectangle is changed *explicitly* by the slider and rectangle's SizeChanged won't trigger.

Comment: Because of absolute positioning the slider doesn't change the size of the rectangle instead it only modifies the x,y coordinates of the rectangle so it will not affect size changed.

Comment: It changes Width and Height properties of Rectangle, see the bindings.

Comment: @edwabr123 Hi, `Rectangle` is a `Shape` which width and height properties are not the same as Control's calculations. As @Vignesh says, in Canvas, Element with absolute positioning, SizeChanged event will be trigger after `Measure` and `Arrange`. This is the design of Canvas. If you want to capture the `SizeChanged` event inside Canvas, consider using Control, such as `Border` or `StackPanel`.

Comment: Hi @RichardZhang-MSFT, according to docs SizeChanged event "Occurs when either the ActualHeight or the ActualWidth property changes value on a FrameworkElement." In the code above, Slider's value is linked to Rectangle's Width and Height (see XAML). When you move slider, Rectangle_SizeChanged callback should trigger but it doesn't. In WPF this works as expected.

Comment: Hi, I have sent a message to the engineer about this issue. Before getting a valid response, I suggest you use `Grid` or other `Panel` as a Rectangle container and put it in the `Canvas`. This will allow the Rectangle to successfully trigger the `SizeChanged` event.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT, thanks for taking care of this. I ended up writing custom Canvas control.